# Django channels socket not connecting to consumer

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, websocket, django-channels

I'm new to socket programming & I'm kindof stuck with an issue here. My client is not connecting to consumer.

**JavaScript Code**

```
<script>
    // websocket scripts
    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/test/")
</script>
```

**Routing**

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            [
                url(r'^ws/test', consumers.TestConsumer),
            ]
        )
    ),
})
```

**The error**

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/test/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/test-view/` instead of `ws://127.0.0.1:8000/test-view/`

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            [
                url(r'^ws/test-view', consumers.TestConsumer),
            ]
        )
    ),
})
```

Here `'webosocket'` defines that you are using `ws://` protocol but `url(r'^ws/test-view', consumers.TestConsumer)` defines that you want to add `/ws/test-view/` after localhost to connect to it.

Comment: That unfortunately did not work, it seemed like before it was trying to connect and there was a small delay before error. This was rejected instantly

Comment: Can you tell me the logs of django server, when you try to connect to it? Also, can you tell me how are you running django server?

Comment: Actually now its `(WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/test-view/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
(anonymous) @ (index):18`

Comment: `python manage.py runserver` to run the server and there are no errors appearing on the terminal

Comment: here the url is still `ws://127.0.0.1:8000/test-view/`

Comment: `var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/test-view/")`. You should use this

Comment: Pasted the wrong error sorry about that, I have updated it. Seems like there is an issue on the django side but terminal is clear, no errors.

Comment: Can you try removing auth layer `AuthMiddlewareStack`?

Comment: Marked you as answer as that was the main issue. The other one is django side so I can probably figure that out. Thanks alot man that was really helpful. Was stuck on this for 2 hours now